# Ошибка при вызове указателя на метод класса в C++

Tags: c++, функции

Возникла необходимость объявить указатель на метод класса в C++.

```
enum point_type { INSIDE, BORDER, OUTSIDE };

template<typename T>
class Poligon;
```

Внутри класса есть метод p_in_poligon_eo с сигнатурой:

```
Poligon<T>::point_type p_in_poligon_eo(Point<T>& p);
```

Пытаюсь инициализировать указатель на функцию в таком виде:

```
Poligon<T>::point_type(Poligon<T>::* p_in_poligon)(Point<T> &) = &Poligon<T>::p_in_poligon_eo;
```

Вроде бы успешно.

Пытаюсь вызывать функцию по указателю так:

```
point_type p_t = (*p_in_poligon)(Point<T>(i, j));
```

Воникает ошибка:

```
Ошибка C2171 *: недопустимо для операндов типа "Poligon<int>::point_type (__thiscall Poligon<int>::* )(Point<int> &)
```

Документация предлагает вызывать вот так:

```
point_type p_t = (this -> *p_in_poligon)(Point<T>(i, j))
```

Возникает новая ошибка:

```
C2059   синтаксическая ошибка: *    GFrameW32   d:\боты\создание почт\уроки\универ\3 курс\компьютерная графика\gframew32\gframew32\graphics.cpp 178
```

Пробовал также 
`p_in_poligon(Point<T>(i, j)` - не помогает.

Подскажите, как правильно сделать мною задуманное?

Comment: Оператор `->*` это не то же самое, что `-> *`: `(this->*p_in_poligon)(Point<T>(i, j))`

Comment: Не думаю, что в классе может возникнуть необходимость в указателе на свой метод

Comment: Децствительно, поменяв -> * на ->* я получил нужны результат. Вы не подскажите в чём разница между этими операторами?

Answer (score 0):

Декларация

```
Poligon<T>::point_type p_in_poligon_eo(Point<T>& p);
```

принимает только `lvalue` аргумент. А вы даёте временный объект `rvalue`.

```
point_type p_t = (this -> *p_in_poligon)(Point<T>(i, j))
```

Исправить можно передавая с `const` аргументом или по значению или как ссылку на `rvalue` объект.

```
Poligon<T>::point_type p_in_poligon_eo(Point<T>const & p);
Poligon<T>::point_type p_in_poligon_eo(Point<T> p);
Poligon<T>::point_type p_in_poligon_eo(Point<T>&& p);
```

Comment: Вы правы. Мне дейстивтельно не стоилло передавать rvalue вместо ожидаемого lvalue.